# Send data to partial view

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Want to implement search functionality using partial view for the returned data.

My html :

```
<select id="searchSelect">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Title">Title</option>
    <option value="Category">Category</option>
    <option value="ISBN">ISBN</option>
</select>

@Html.DropDownList("Categories", "Select Category")
<input type="text" id="SearchBy" placeholder="sometext" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="search">Search</a>
```

Now, how to pass these values to partial view ?? - And how to load partial ??

I have made this function :

```
$(document).on("click", ".search", function () {
    var searchBy = $("#searchSelect option:selected").val();
    if (searchBy == "All") {
        var text = $("#SearchBy").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Search",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "data": text }),
            success: function (r) {
                $(".load").html(r.data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But i realize that this way i should use JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement `Search` action in your default controller to return `PartialViewResult` and then in the success callback of the ajax request you will receive the desired html.

The **Ajax** call:

```
[ ... ]

var text = $("#SearchBy").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Search",
    contentType: "application/json", // Specify the content type
    data: JSON.stringify({ "data": text }), // Here you pass data to the controller's action
    success: function (response) {
        $(".load").html(response);
    }
});

[ ... ]
```

Search Action in **HomeController**:

```
public ActionResult Search(string data)
{
    // Here use data, call some service or whatever
    MyModel myModel = myService.GetMyModel();

    [ ... ] 

    return PartialView(someModel);
}
```

**Search.cshtml** partial view:

```
@model MyModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>@Model.Prop1</h1>
<h2>@Model.Prop2</h2>

[ ... ]
```